# Save Dojox GFX Canvas as SVG

Tags: svg, dojo, gfx

Is there a way to serialize a Dojox GFX canvas as SVG?

I am looking for a way to save my Dojox GFX canvas contents in a way which can be exported as a graphics file (SVG, PNG, JPG, etc.) which could be easily saved or printed, and SVG seemed the most likely.

I found a reference to a function dojox.gfx.utils.toSvg, which looked perfect:

http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/gfx/utils/toSvg

But this function does not exist in my Dojo (1.1) implementation, and is not mentioned in the Dojo Toolkit documentation, so I am not sure if it exists.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [new in 1.4](http://docs.dojocampus.org/releasenotes/1.4#dojox-gfx). Most probably it can be backported to earlier versions, if you have time on hands.

I didn't understand the part about "[it] is not mentioned in the Dojo Toolkit documentation, so I am not sure if it exists" — you gave the link to the documentation yourself. And I pretty sure you can find examples of its use in /dojox/gfx/tests/

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The DojoCampus page seemed to say it was available since version 1.0, but perhaps I misunderstood that.

By "not mentioned in the Dojo Toolkit documentation", I was referring to http://api.dojotoolkit.org/, but perhaps that hasn't been updated for 1.4 yet. Thanks, David.